# Metabase Get Report Source Data for each Report

Tags: metabase

This is my query to get the logs to my reports of Metabase:

```
SELECT view_log.user_id as "User Id Log",
       CONCAT (U.first_name,' ', U.Last_name) as UserFullName,
       U.last_login as "LastTimeUserLogin",
       DATE_TRUNC('month',view_log.timestamp) as "DateQuery",
       view_log.model as "Log Model",
       view_log.model_id as "Log Model Id",
       report_dashboard.id as "report_dashboard_ID",
       report_dashboard.name as "Report Dashboard Name",
       report_dashboard.description as "Report Dashboard Description",
       CONCAT('https:.....', view_log.model, '/', view_log.model_id,'-',report_dashboard.name)


FROM public.view_log
    INNER JOIN report_dashboard on report_dashboard.id = model_id
    INNER JOIN report_dashboardcard RD on report_dashboard.id = RD.dashboard_id
    LEFT JOIN core_user U on view_log.user_id = U.id

where view_log.timestamp > '2023-02-01' and view_log.user_id != 166

ORDER BY "DateQuery" DESC;
```

I would like to add for each log the database source of the data in the field
"DatabaseSource" Like in this example:

[image]

How I could query this information in metabase?